# Macro for week number

Tags: macros, datetime

Is there a macro or package to calculate the [ISO week number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) or alternative can someone help me with one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no package as such,  but Taco Hoekwater, wrote a macro called `calendarweek` that you can use. You find it on CTAN at [weekday](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/misc/calendarweek.tex).

Remark. The macro returns 0 for the first 4 days of 2015, while the 5th day returns week 2. Because the algorithm is not explained, there does not seem to be an easy way to find out what is wrong. Most weeks have the correct number though.

Here is a minimal example, as to how to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% calendarweek.tex
%% 2006 (C) Taco Hoekwater, public domain
%% Watch out: Dec 29 can be week 1 of the next year; and Jan 3 can be
%% week 53 of the previous year.

\def\Expr#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}

\def\Modulonumber#1#2{\Expr{#2-((((#2+(#1/2))/#1)-1)*#1)}}
\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2-#1)/(2*#1)}}

\def\Mod#1#2{\Modulonumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
\def\Div#1#2{\Divisionnumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}

\def\Jday#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{#1+\Div{((153*(\Expr{#2+(12*(\Div{14-#2}{12}))-3}))+2)}
     {5}+365*(\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{4})-
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{100})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{400})-32045 }}

\def\cwhlp#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{\Mod {\Mod {\Mod {\Expr
     {\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}+31741-\Mod{\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}}{7}}}%
     {146097}}{36524}}{1461}}}

\def\calendarweek#1#2#3%
  {\Expr{\Expr{\Div{\Expr{\Mod{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}-
    \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}{365}+
         \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}}{7} +1}}}

\begin{document}

\calendarweek{28}{2}{2011}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I made a commented and corrected version of that code in a [separate answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602122/123129). It solves the issue with years that start with Thursday (e.g. 2004, 2015, ...).

Answer (score 4):

I took a closer look at the above code from Taco Hoekwater posted in the answer by Yiannis Lazarides and tried to understand it. The result is a commented version without the mentioned error, which occurred for all years starting with a Thursday (e.g. 2004, 2015, ...), that lead to a -1 instead of a 1 for the first week.

The integer division that is at the very beginning led to the problem. (Unfortunately, I only looked at it at the end :/) In exchange, however, there are now comments almost everywhere. Only 2 magic numbers I could not explain yet.

I also removed some unnecessary `\Expr` and brackets. It is just an arithmetic calculation without conditions or temporary variables. Both could make it more efficient. But I did without that now, because I didn't want to change the code too much.

This is a good example of why you should create code that is readable and understandable to others. This makes adjustments and corrections easier.

**Code:**

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/macro-for-week-number
%% calendarweek.tex
%% 2006 (C) Taco Hoekwater, public domain
%% Watch out: Dec 29 can be week 1 of the next year; and Jan 3 can be
%% week 53 of the previous year.
%%
%% 2021 (C) dexteritas
%% corrected and commented
%% Years that begin with a thursday will now give week 1 instead of -1 for the first week.

\def\Expr#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}

% modulo
\def\Modulonumber#1#2{\Expr{#2 - \Divisionnumber{#1}{#2} * #1}}
% integer division (reminder is discarded)
\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(#2 + #1/2) / #1 - 1}} % <- NEW: works also for 0/x=0

% modulo with Expr
% #1 modulo #2
\def\Mod#1#2{\Modulonumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
% integer division with Expr
% floor(#1 / #2)
\def\Div#1#2{\Divisionnumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}

\def\Jday#1#2#3{%
    \Expr{%
        % day
        #1%
        %
        % Offset day of year from 1st of march for given month
        % returns for given month: 1: 306, 2: 337, 3: 0, 4: 31, 5: 61, 6: 92, 7: 122, 8: 153, 9: 184, 10: 214, 11: 245, 12: 275
        % magic number 153: 153/5=30.6 (leads to the sequence above (adds 30 or 31 for each month)
        +\Div{%
            (153*(%
                % month + (12 if month is jan or feb else 0) - 3 returns: jan = 10, feb = 11, mar = 0, apr = 1, ...
                #2 +(12*(%
                    % if month (#2) is 1 (= january) or 2 (= february) than 1 else 0
                    % \Div{14-#2}{12}
                    \Div{14-#2}{12}%
                ))-3%
            )+2)%
        }{%
            5%
        }%
        %
        % Sum 365 for each year:
        % 365 * (year + 4800 - (1 if month is jan or feb else 0))
        % 4800 (= 12 * 400) is a cycle of same years
        +365*(#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12}))%
        %
        % calculate leapyear if dividable by: 4 yes (1), 100 no (-1), 400 yes (1)
        % add 1 for every 4th year (see leapyear definition)
        +(\Div{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}{4})%
        % subtract 1 for every 100th year (see leapyear definition)
        -(\Div{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}{100})%
        % add 1 for every 400th year (see leapyear definition)
        +(\Div{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}{400})%
        %
        % magic number? 32045
        -32045%
    }
}

\def\cwhlp#1#2#3{%
    % returns wednesday of the current week counted within a period of 4 years
    % return value is in [0, 1460]
    \Expr{%
        \Mod{%
            \Mod{%
                \Mod{%
                    \Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}%
                    % magic number? 31741
                    +31741%
                    % day of week 0=monday, 1=tuesday, ...
                    -\Mod{\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}}{7}%
                }{%
                    % days of 400 years: 146097 = 365 * 400 + 100 - 4 + 1
                    % +100=400/4 (for dividable by 4 is leapyear)
                    % -4=400/-100 (for dividable by 100 is not a leapyear)
                    % +1=400/400 (for dividable by 400 is a leapyear)
                    146097%
                }%
            }{%
                % days of 100 years: 36524 = 365 * 100 + 25 - 1
                % +25 (for dividable by 4 is leapyear)
                % -1 (for dividable by 100 is not a leapyear)
                36524%
            }%
         }{%
             % days of 4 years: 1461 = 365 * 4 + 1 (day for 1 leapyear)
             1461%
         }%
     }%
}

\def\calendarweek#1#2#3{%
    \Expr{%
        % 1460 => 364 + 1 => 365
        % 364 / 7 = 52 (weeks)
        % 365 / 7 = 53 (weeks)
        \Div{%
            % wednesday of current week within the year (?)
            % value is in [0, 364]
            \Mod{%
                \cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}%
                % subtract 1 if \cwhlp is 1460
                -\Div{%
                    \cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}%
                }{%
                    % days of 4 years without leapyear days: 1460 = 365 * 4
                    1460%
                }%
            }{%
                % days of 1 years without leapyear day: 365
                365%
            }%
            %
            % adds 1 if \cwhlp is 1460 again (?)
            +\Div{%
                \cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}%
            }{%
                % days of 4 years without leapyear days: 1460 = 365 * 4
                1460%
            }%
        }{%
            7%
        }%
        % to start with week 1 instead of 0
        +1%
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

2021-06-21 is week \calendarweek{21}{06}{2021}.

\medskip
\textbf{The week of the first 7 days of a year:}

\foreach \xyear in {2000,...,2030}{
    \xyear:
    \foreach \xday in {1,...,7}{%
        \calendarweek{\xday}{01}{\xyear}
    }
    
}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: result of latex code]

Answer (score 3):

Here is expl3:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/week.php#calcweekno
\int_new:N \l_week_number_year_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_month_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_day_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_a_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_b_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_c_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_s_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_e_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_f_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_g_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_d_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_n_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_W_int

\cs_new:Nn \week_number:nnn {

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_year_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_month_int { #2 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_day_int { #3 }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_month_int } < { 3 } % jan or feb
  { % true

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_a_int { \l_week_number_year_int - 1 }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
      \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

    \int_zero:N \l_week_number_e_int

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int - 1
      + 31 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 1 ) }

  } % end true
  { % false

    \int_set_eq:NN \l_week_number_a_int \l_week_number_year_int

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
      \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_e_int { \l_week_number_s_int + 1 }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int
      + \int_div_truncate:nn {
        153 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 3 ) + 2 } { 5 }
      + 58 + \l_week_number_s_int }

  } % end false

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_g_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_a_int + \l_week_number_b_int } { 7 }  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_d_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_f_int + \l_week_number_g_int
      - \l_week_number_e_int } { 7 }  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_n_int {
    \l_week_number_f_int + 3 - \l_week_number_d_int }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } < { 0 }
  { %true

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 53
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_g_int
        - \l_week_number_s_int } { 5 } }

  } % end true
  { % false

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } > { 364
      + \l_week_number_s_int }
    { % true

      \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 1 }

    } % end true
    { % false

      \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {
          \l_week_number_n_int } { 7 } + 1 }

    } % end false

  } % end false

}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\week_number:nnn { 2010 } { 01 } { 01 }
\int_to_arabic:n { \l_week_number_W_int }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

The `datenumber` package can give you the day as number. By subtracting the number of Jan 1st of the same year and adding one you can get the day of the year.
The number of the week is then about this number divided by seven.

Because ISO weeks start by definition with a Monday you have to add an offset:

```
[ISO week number] = 
 floor( ( [number of selected date] - [number of first Monday of the year] + 1 ) / 7 ) + 1
```

The package also gives you the possibility to check the day of the week, which allows you to find the first Monday of the year.

I'm not sure if I understood ISO week numbers correctly and I might be off with the equations (it's 1.30am), but you get the idea.

Comment: The ISO week number starts with a Thursday! So some months can have 5 weeks and others 4. It is a somewhat convoluted scheme. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @saltypen: The Wikipedia article you linked states: "Weeks start with Monday". Ok, I see now: "Week 1 := the week with the year's first Thursday in it (the ISO 8601 definition)". But the principle is the same!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I determine the first Thursday of the year?

Comment: @saltypen: The package gives you the day-of-the-week as number in `datedayname` Mo=1,Su=7 => Thu=5. You look which day-of-the-week the 1.1. is, then you simply calculate (5 - weekday(1.1.) ) modulo 7. The result is the number of days you have to add to 1.1. to get to the first Thursday.