# Print week number in title

Tags: datetime, calendar

Is there is a way to insert week number instead to type it directly?

My current document code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}                   
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\author{The Author}
\title{Week 12 2014}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you willing to write `\calendarweek{28}{5}{2014}`? Then have a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10950 and put that in your `\title{}`. If not, you should rephrase your question in order to get a `\week{\today}` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10950):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\def\Expr#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}

\def\Modulonumber#1#2{\Expr{#2-((((#2+(#1/2))/#1)-1)*#1)}}
\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2-#1)/(2*#1)}}

\def\Mod#1#2{\Modulonumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
\def\Div#1#2{\Divisionnumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}

\def\Jday#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{#1+\Div{((153*(\Expr{#2+(12*(\Div{14-#2}{12}))-3}))+2)}
     {5}+365*(\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{4})-
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{100})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{400})-32045 }}

\def\cwhlp#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{\Mod {\Mod {\Mod {\Expr
     {\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}+31741-\Mod{\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}}{7}}}%
     {146097}}{36524}}{1461}}}

\def\calendarweek#1#2#3%
  {\Expr{\Expr{\Div{\Expr{\Mod{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}-
    \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}{365}+
         \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}}{7} +1}}}
\author{The Author}
\title{CW \calendarweek{28}{5}{2014}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've googled for another option but seems \calendarweek macro is single solution for this case.